# Passing scanf entries to stdarg function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to do a program that does the average of n numbers using the vararg function

```
average(int numberOfValues, ...);
```

Where the entries are the numbers of values to get the average and the values itself (...).

The question is: Can I make a routine to get those values from scanf? I thought to build a array with the numberOfValues size and call the vararg function then, but I can't pass a array for a function (at least without pointers). Am I on the away to the answer? I also thought in to pass the numberOfValues and values as main function arguments (at least for testing) to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you are having an instance of [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Note that if you don't know the number of values before calling `average()` then a variable argument function doesn't make much sense. If you want to compute the average of numbers using `scanf()` do it directly by computing the sum and counting the number of values. If you know how to write a variable arguments function, you would not be using `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do something like

```
int a, b, c;
scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
average(3, a, b, c);
```

or maybe

```
int a[3];
scanf("%d%d%d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2]);
average(3, a[0], a[1], a[2]);
```

But if you don't know (until the user types them) how many values there will be, then yes, you probably want to store them in an array, but no, a varargs function to compute the average is not going to be useful.

A limitation of varargs functions (conventional ones, at least) is that the number of arguments (for a particular call, that is) must always be known at compile time.

So, instead, you might want to write

```
average(int numberOfValues, int theValues[])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

where you pass the values as an array, not as a variable argument list.  This will probably be both easier to write, and more generally useful.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a limitation. Variable arguments at run time don't even make sense at all.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Well, it may not be a limitation for "conventional" uses of varargs, but believe me, there are lots of people who have wanted to construct variable-length arguments lists at run time.  (It's what I call the "inverse varargs problem".)